# Envelope of I/Q data

Tags: signal-analysis

In finding the envelope of the I/Q data set (which is a complex data set, Inphase /Quadrature data) I cannot use `envelop(x)` in MATLAB, as it requires the real-valued "X" in MATLAB, so got an error. Does anyone have a suggestion for solving this, finding envelope from I/Q data? Thanks,

Comment: Hi. Perhaps the material at the following web page will be of some use to you: https://www.dsprelated.com/showarticle/938.php

Answer (score 2):

If your signal is an analytical signal, then `envelope(real(X))` would simply be your answer. This would be identical to using the Hilbert transform to extract the Quadrature part of the signal from the Inphase part. If your signal is not analytical, your envelope would simply be:
$$G = \sqrt{I^2 + Q^2} $$